# Cannot console into new created Openstack instance

Tags: python, linux, cloud, openstack, devstack

I installed Openstack Mitaka using Devstack on an Ubuntu virtual machine in Virtualbox. After installation, things seemed to be alright. Then I start a new Cirros instance, and it succeeded. However, when I tried to console this instance using `ip nets exec xxxxxx ssh cirros@172.24.4.3` it returned `ssh: connect to host 172.24.4.3 port 22: no route to host`. Result for `ip nets exec xxxxxx ping 172.24.4.3` is `Destination Host Unreachable`.

I checked the `ip netsh`, the result was like:

> qrouter-xxxxxxx
>
> qdhcp-xxxxxx

If I use `ip nets exec qrouter-xxxxxx ip addr show` , the result includes:

> 127.0.0.1, 10.0.0.1, 172.24.4.2, and another item with no ip address.

If I user `ip nets exec qdhcp-xxxxxx ip addr show`, the result includes:

> 127.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2

The instance is connected to public network as shown in Openstack Dashboard. And if I try to connect to the console in WebUI - Dashboard/Compute/Instances/xxxx/Console, there was an error shown on the page, saying:

> Error response. Error code 404.Message: File not found.
>
> Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.

So how can I console into the instances created by Openstack? Is it something to do with the network configuration?

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: It is impossible to help you with the information you have provided, we know nothing about your network configuration, logs etc. Having said that, I have just commented on a very similar question and I believe you are doing the same thing wrong. I suggest you to go through the Networking part of the documentation [here](https://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/install-guide-ubuntu/neutron.html). If everything seems to be ok, check [this](https://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/install-guide-ubuntu/launch-instance.html) and see if you can launch a new instance and access it.